# How to use TouchWrapper component in Image Forward List Display?

Tags: python, alexa-skills-kit, alexa-presentation-language

In the documentation, content is not enough to exactly implement TouchWrapper component. Anyone who could help?

I have referred-
https://developer.amazon.com/docs/alexa-presentation-language/apl-touchwrapper.html

https://medium.com/@punkpocko/alexa-apl-touch-wrappers-75d62784b3e8

```
def can_handle(self, handler_input):
    return handler_input.request_envelope.request.type = 'Alexa.Presentation.APL.UserEvent' and handler_input.request_envelope.request.arguments.length>0 and (handler_input.request_envelope.request.arguments[0] == "Desi Flavors" or handler_input.request_envelope.request.arguments[0] == 'Global Flavors')

def handle(self, handler_input):
    if handler_input.request_envelope.request.arguments[0] == "Desi Flavors":
        dish ='Desi Flavors'
    elif handler_input.request_envelope.request.arguments[0] == "Global Flavors":
        dish ='Global Flavors'
    return dish
```

Here is JSON- 
{
    "type":"TouchWrapper",
    "item":{
        "type":"Text",
        "text":"",
        "color":"",
        "fontSize":""
    },
    "OnPress":{
        "type":"SendEvent",
        "arguments":[
            "Desi Flavors",
            "Global Flavors"
        ]
    }

}

I expect the output that if one chooses Desi Flavors it should get stored in the variable(dish).

Comment: Correct Answer in Python - def can_handle(self, handler_input):
    return handler_input.request_envelope.request.source['type'] = ='TouchWrapper'  and (handler_input.request_envelope.request.arguments[0] == "Desi Flavors" or handler_input.request_envelope.request.arguments[0] == 'Global Flavors')

def handle(self, handler_input):
    if handler_input.request_envelope.request.arguments[0] == "Desi Flavors":
        dish ='Desi Flavors'
    elif handler_input.request_envelope.request.arguments[0] == "Global Flavors":
        dish ='Global Flavors'
    return dish

Comment: this entry is not written as a question. what are you asking exactly?